# Replace object with static fields with the values of the fields in webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I have a module that looks like this:

```
let Info = {};

Info.VALUE_ONE = 123;
Info.VALUE_TWO = 456;
Info.VALUE_THREE = 789;

module.exports = Info;
```

I'd like this module to disappear completely from the code after it's compiled and just have the values 123, 456 and 789 inlined where applicable- how would one do this with Webpack?

Comment: Can you live with the reference to Info everywhere?  i.e. not reassign info to another variable and expect the inlines to propagate.

Comment: @aaaaaa I'm not sure what you mean- have Info as a global variable? When I require Info, it's always put into a variable called Info if this is what you're asking

Comment: yes that's what I mean.  Another caveat to the solution I have in mind is that you won't be able to do `const { VALUE_ONE } = require('path/to/info');`.  Let me play around with some code and I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to use [string-replace-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-replace-loader) to inline `Info.<key>` to `<value>`.  Then to remove the module itself you have two options.

- **option 1**: keep your commonjs syntax and use [null-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-replace-loader) to transform the module into an empty object.  The caveat with this approach is I don't see any way to remove references to the module because webpack safely assumes the `require` statement itself may produce a side-effect<sup>1</sup>
- **option 2**: start using es6 import and export and make use of webpack's [module-concatenation-plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/module-concatenation-plugin/).  This will place info.js in the same scope as its consumers, allowing the minifier to remove its code (because there will be no references to the `Info` object).  You will also need to use [esm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/esm) to load the webpack configuration file via `npx webpack -r esm`

so given a directory structure of:

```
- index.js
- info.js
- webpack.config.js
```

This code should give you what you're looking for (I used the code-snippet syntax to make them collapsable - the code is not runnable)

**code for option 1**

```js
    // info.js
    module.exports {
      VALUE_ONE: 123,
      VALUE_TWO: 456,
      VALUE_THREE: 789,
    }


    // index.js
    const Info = require('./info')
    console.log(Info.VALUE_ONE)


    // webpack.config.js
    const Info = require('./info')

    const searchAndReplaceInfo = createSearchAndReplaceInfo(Info)

    module.exports = {
      mode: 'development',
      entry: './index.js',
      output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: __dirname
      },
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: path.resolve(__dirname, 'info.js'),
            use: 'null-loader'
          }, {
            exclude: /\/node_modules\//,
            loader: 'string-replace-loader',
            options: {
              multiple: searchAndReplaceInfo
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }

    function createSearchAndReplaceInfo(Info) {
      return Object.keys(Info).map(key => [key, Info[key]]).map(toSearchAndReplace)
    }

    function toSearchAndReplace([key, value]) {
      return {
        search: 'Info.' + key,
        replace: '' + value
      }
    }
```

**code for option 2**

```js
    // info.js
    export default {
      VALUE_ONE: 123,
      VALUE_TWO: 456,
      VALUE_THREE: 789,
    }


    // index.js
    import Info from './info'
    console.log(Info.VALUE_ONE)


    // webpack.config.js
    import Info from './info'
    import webpack from 'webpack'

    const searchAndReplaceInfo = createSearchAndReplaceInfo(Info)

    export default {
      mode: 'development',
      entry: './index.js',
      output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: __dirname
      },
      plugins: [ new webpack.optimize.ModuleConcatenationPlugin() ],
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            exclude: /\/node_modules\//,
            loader: 'string-replace-loader',
            options: {
              multiple: searchAndReplaceInfo
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }

    function createSearchAndReplaceInfo(Info) {
      return Object.keys(Info).map(key => [key, Info[key]]).map(toSearchAndReplace)
    }

    function toSearchAndReplace([key, value]) {
      return {
        search: 'Info.' + key,
        replace: '' + value
      }
    }
```

**[side-effect<sup>1</sup>](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/#mark-the-file-as-side-effect-free)**

> A "side effect" is defined as code that performs a special behavior when imported, other than exposing one or more exports. An example of this are polyfills, which affect the global scope and usually do not provide an export.

Comment: Going with approach one, I've got a strange error. My Info file has entries like Info.TEST_ONE = 123; and Info.TEST_TWO = 456; and a replacement has ended up as "123_TWO" (from "Info.TEST_ONE") and this raised an error for invalid JS luckily- it looks like something to do with underscores

Comment: I can't tell without a reproduction, but I'm assuming it's data related (i.e. the contents of `Info`).  There shouldn't be anything magical happening with string-replace-loader, the search/replace logic is [pretty simple](https://github.com/Va1/string-replace-loader/blob/master/lib/replace.js)

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you may want to use the [`webpack.DefinePlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/), which allows you to inline global values at compile time.

**webpack.config.js**

```
plugins: [
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    Info: require('./info.js'),
  }),
  //...
]
```

---

As an example, your source code would be transformed as below:

**source**

```
let value = null;

switch (value) {
  case Info.VALUE_ONE:
    //...
  case Info.VALUE_TWO:
    //...
  case Info.VALUE_THREE:
    //...
  default:
    //...
}
```

**output**

```
let value = null;

switch (value) {
  case 123: //...

  case 456: //...

  case 789: //...

  default: //...

}
```

Comment: I tried this initially - only works if you leave out 'const Info = require('path/to/info')`.  I assume it tries to be smart and not overwrite declared variables.

Comment: @aaaaaa not quite sure what you mean? It should still work even if the `require` is assigned to another variable.

Comment: what I mean is if you have `const Info = require('path/to/info')` in the file which you're trying to inline, then the DefinePlugin won't overwrite Info because it's being declared as a constant.  It seems to only overwrite undefined global variables.

Comment: I see, you're correct. The `info` module shouldn't be used in your application code. `webpack.DefinePlugin` happens at compile time, and won't replace a **locally** scoped `Info` variable of the same name if it exists.

Comment: Right - so then if having an implicitly global 'Info' object is ok for OP then this solution is the simplest.

Comment: Guess this is good solution as original authours plan looks horrible.